# Use Charles Proxy to route https request to local http server

Tags: macos, https, proxy, charles-proxy

I have Charles Proxy set up to look at outgoing https requests, and I need to re-route traffic from one server to a local http server.

I have a MacOSX machine that is set up this way: I have an ethernet connection that I hardwire, and share the internet connection via the airport interface. On a second machine, I've installed the Charles cert, and when I connect via the shared interface. I can see the traffic (unencrypted) in Charles, so I know the communications and certs are all working properly.

I need to intercept all the https traffic going to one server (https://www.foo.com) to a local http server (localhost:8001). I've tried using Map Remote, but it doesn't seem to unencrypt the traffic before forwarding it (or possibly it re-encrypts it).

How can I configure Charles  to do this? (or, please point me to any other software package, if Charles isn't capable of this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was happening, there were two issues.

I had misconfigured the Map Remote entry, and my two different clients (MyApp and curl) were hitting two different servers - the app was hitting the correct server (locally) but the request was malformed.

Curl from the macOSX box where the proxy was running was NOT looping through the proxy, since I hadn't included the -x localhost:8888 flag.